# $index as a parameter : multiple if statement issue

Tags: function, if-statement, indexing, parameters, echo

Please take a look at this function :

```
function my_func($index_bis) {
    if (!is_int($index_bis) || $index_bis > 5 || $index_bis < 0) return;
    elseif ($index_bis = 5) : echo 'This';
    elseif ($index_bis = 1) : echo 'That';
    endif;
}
```

What's wrong with this? I actually can't understand where is the mistake...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What is this? PHP?
And what are you attempting to do?

How about this:

```
function my_func($index_bis) {
    if (!is_int($index_bis) || $index_bis > 5 || $index_bis < 0){
        $str = $index_bis;
    }
    elseif ($index_bis == 5) {
        $str='This';
    }
    elseif ($index_bis == 1) {
        $str='That';
    }
return $str;
}
```

It's pretty atypical to put anything after "return"; and I think "return" stops the function, effectively.

Edit: FOREACH method.

If you are building html from two related variables, FOREACH is a great method for handling them, as you can set a data "key" and "value" for each item in the array.

By default, the "key" in PHP is assigned a number, starting from 0 and progressing through increasing integers. You have the option of naming these keys, instead of using the PHP-assigned default.

So consider setting up your array as such:

```
$newArray = (
    'tab name' => 'label name',
    'apples'   => 'red',
    'oranges'  => 'orange',
    );
```

Wherein the item to the left of the "=>" is always the key, and the item to the right is always the value.

Then, you can add more elements to this array in your code by using this line:

```
$newArray['bananas'] = 'yellow';
```

Note the key (tab) name, with square brackets (because it is the key name) and single quotes (because it is a string).

Now that you have an array, you can "walk" it using a FOREACH loop and echoing the html. Here is the code:

```
 foreach($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tab>$key</tab> : ";
    echo "<label>$value</label>
    echo "<br /";
}
```

This will output the html below:

```
 <tab>tab name</tab> : <label>label name</label><br />
 <tab>apples</tab> : <label>red</label><br />
 <tab>oranges</tab> : <label>orange</label><br />
 <tab>bananas</tab> : <label>yellow</label><br />
```

Very useful. Have fun!

Note: There are likely better ways to do this, but I'm sharing this one as a simple solution. And also, because you shouldn't go further without understanding both FOREACH and simple arrays.

Note: If you want to incorporate more than two variables, you will need a more complex data structure. In PHP, these are called "multidimensional arrays". Give it a read. Beyond that, there are still more methods for handling data (ie. "objects").

Comment: Yes, it's PHP, sorry to have forgotten about a PHP tag in my post.

This code was an example only. What i expect to do in my real function is to add the proper amount of column of a tab system. Then, if $index_bis == 5, display 5 tabs. If $index_bis ==1, display only one tab.

And for each value, i'll have the HTML associated.

The code will be probably redundant, but <I'm sure there is a way to add part of code which only contains the additional code (eg. between 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3and 4, 4 and 5).

Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Oh, and the return was there to stop the function, it's why I add it. If $index_bis isn't a integer, or >5, or <0, then return nothing.

Comment: Example code is fine – perfect, in fact. Alexandre, would it be a better approach, from a code-design perspective, to create an array of the tab names, then use a FOREACH statement to walk the array and output the tabs? The IF statement seems far too complex for what you suggest here. This would avoid the redundant use of the function. I would need to understand the source of the data you are using to create the tabs to comment with more clarity.

Comment: I have successfully achieved what I wished. But, as you expected, it's a bit redundant. I have bought a books for PHP, updated for PHP 7 (so, up to date), because it's not the first time I need this foreach statement. I'm just unable to understand it properly actually. For the moment, i have achieved what I wanted with IF statement and by displaying part of the code each time : 

    if ($alex_index == 2) {echo $alex_str_1,$alex_str_a;} --- ... --- if ($alex_index == 5) {echo $alex_str_1,$alex_str_2,$alex_str_3,$alex_str_4,$alex_str_a,$alex_str_b,$alex_str_c,$alex_str_d;}

Comment: This can sounds really strange, but my Tabs are made with inputs and labels, which means I had to separate each <label> and <input> code from the html blocks needed to display the content. In short, 2 variable were needed ofr each tab. Don't worry about this post anymore, I have to learn more, and this begin by reading proper books. I'll open another post for another foreach related issue, in order to see how this statement works, but that's all. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds good, Alexandre. Do read up on FOREACH. Here is the PHP manual's link: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php I think I understand what you are doing, and will try to edit my answer above to add a suggested method using FOREACH.

Bonne chance!

Comment: Alex, if this helps at all, I wouldn't mind a checkmark or an upvote, which will allow me to act like a human being on this website. :-P  Thanking you!

Comment: Done, upvoted, but it tells me it will not change anything on the public profile, cause i have less than 15 reputation :p

Comment: Lol! What a strange world that we live in. Okay, thank you Alex. Happy coding!